# Change background image based on URL parts

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to add to my site the capability, where the background will change based on part of the URL using stylesheets.

Example:

```
address/shop/index.php             = background image 1
address/shop/index.php?cPath=22    = background image 2
address/shop/index.php?cPath=23    = background image 3
address/shop/index.php?cPath=24    = background image 4
```

Any ideas? I have looked at Javascript and jQuery but not sure on which one to choose or how to go about it.

Comment: change the class of the `<body>` (or whatever element you want to change the background of) for the generated html. And have different backgrounds for different classes

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are using PHP, so you should be able to do it without javascript. You just need to use PHP's server variables.

Something like

```
 $cPath = $_GET['cPath']; //This allows access to the query part of the url
 if($cPath == 24){
     //set background url
 }
```

Comment: $cPath = $_GET['cPath']; //This allows access to the query part of the url
 if($cPath == 23){
 

} set background:url(WoodenPlank.jpg)
 }

Comment: $cPath = $_GET['cPath']; //This allows access to the query part of the url
 if($cPath == 23){
$bg='background: #000 url(WoodenPlank.jpg);'; 
}

Answer (score 0):

You can always let the part of url surrounded by a tag e.g. `<font>`
So the code would be like:

```
<a>your url link 
    <font class='background1'>part with background1</font>
    <font class='background2'>part with background2</font>
</a>
```

Then in css you can have

```
.background1{background: url('...')}
.background2{background: url('...')}
```

This may be a hackish way but in this way you can at least categorize your 'link parts'.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do this client-side, I'd suggest:

```
var pageBackground = {
    'default' : 'classOne',
    '22' : 'classTwo',
    '23' : 'classThree'
};

document.body.className = pageBackground[window.location.split('cPath=')[1] || 'default'];
```

Coupled with the stylesheet:

```
body.classOne {
    background-image: url(path/to/defaultImage.png);
}
body.classTwo {
    background-image: url(path/to/imageTwo.png);
}
body.classThree {
    background-image: url(path/to/imageThree.png);
}
```

Comment: As long as the JavaScript gets to the client's browser intact then it should work, yes.

Answer (score -1):

on your html page inside the body tag type:

```
<body background="your file">

</body>
```

You can do that on each page that you want a different background and it will override any CSS style that styles the body

Comment: @zerkms its worked for me on every website I have ever designed and eliminates the need for php or jquery that is heavy on DOM...don't see anything horrible about that

Comment: you could eat your soup with a fork and hands - it would work, but using spoon is more convenient. PS: and to clarify - it wasn't me who downvote you (even though I agree this answer deserves it :-)

Comment: I think there's just one file... `index.php`. You would have to create the tag dynamically based on the variable - which gets you to the other answers...